# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server after log files deletion

Tags: centos, webmin

Hi to everyone today I got a problem with full disk and I typed a command which I found on another topic:

```
sudo find /var/log/ -type f -regex '.*\.[0-9]+\.gz$' -delete
```

After this step I can't start httpd, apache or ftp anymore

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So after this command: `systemctl status -l httpd` I noticed that there were some deleted folders and immetiately I created missed log folders like etc/httpd/logs and var/log/virtualmin folder and httpd started normaly but now the problem is with mariadb.

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl status -l mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-26 06:50:31 EDT; 2min 41s ago
  Process: 2928 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 26 06:50:31 server.xxxxx.com systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Mar 26 06:50:31 server.xxxxxx.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 26 06:50:31 server.xxxxx.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Mar 26 06:50:31 server.xxxxx.com systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 06:50:31 server.xxxxx.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
[root@server ~]# systemctl status -l mariadb.service
```

Any Suggestion to get my webserver back online? So httpd is back I have only one issue with the mysql server.

Im using virtualmin on centos 7

Comment: Im sorry for this post but was missing also var/log/mariadb folder so the command deleted alltogether after mariadb folder creation everything is back if any one gets the same problem this is the solution.

Comment: Please post your solution with explanation and accept it as an answer it Will be easier for others in the future if its marked as a valid answer. Comment are not made to last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I would like to post the solution but I want to explain it from the begining.

My issue started with the full disk problem, filesystem was full and I couldn't login in my wordpress sites because device didn't have more space for the database.

You can check it with the following command: `df -h`

So the problem came with the log files, If you are using virtualmin you can delete log files via cronjob from webmin > system > log ratation section which I didn't know before.

If you have the same issue simply delete logs in **etc/httpd/logs**, **var/log/virtualmin** and **var/log/mariadb**

I did a mistake using the command: `sudo find /var/log/ -type f -regex '.*\.[0-9]+\.gz$' -delete` I'm calling it a mistake because it deleted also the mentioned folders but it also saved my life.

I created the missed folders manualy using filezilla in sftp and rebooted the server than httpd and apache started again and everything is going fine now.

Don't forget to use cron job for logs deletion, daily, weekly or monthly you can choose the options in webmin.

If the httpd not starting simply use the command `systemctl status -l httpd` it will tell where is the problem, also for the mariadb you can use the command: `systemctl status -l mariadb.service`